# Is it possible to specify the client library using swagger codegen?

Tags: swagger-codegen

When generating a client based on Swagger metadata, is it possible to specify or configure things somehow that the output should use some other client library?

So if it was a C# client for example, to automatically replace the HttpClient or RestSharp client (I don't recall what it is now as I have not used it in a while) with some custom library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

The codegen uses templates and configuation java classes to generate code in different languages. If you're willing to modify these templates and classes this would be a quite simple modification.

You can find the opensource repository here [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)

The template files for each language can be found here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources

Java config classes:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages

List of template variables:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Mustache-Template-Variables

Template are written in mustache:
https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Interesting read if you want to start from scratch:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/How-to-add-a-generator-for-a-new-language-or-framework

Comment: Please could you direct me to any clues/links/info/help on modifying the template for a specific language?

Comment: updated my original answer with more links that should get you started.